# extra rows to extra columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

EDIT
I figured it out - was easier than I thought - just had to set index to true - see below

```
import numpy as npg
import pandas as pd
original_data = np.array([[1,0,0,10,1530,0.1,2,-49.0756686364,163.856504545],
                 [1,0,0,10,8250,0.1,2,-84.7795213636,264.205363636],
[1,0,0,10,20370,0.1,2,-245.585863636,662.467227273],
[1,0,0,10,33030,0.1,2,-290.468136364,1107.19936364],
[1,0,0,10,47970,0.1,2,-308.668681818,1584.18090909],
[1,0,0,10,63090,0.1,2,-244.954186364,1932.43454545],
[1,0,0,10,93090,0.1,2,-9.5453963636,1794.01636364],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,1530,0.1,2,-36.28640875,136.9883],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,8250,0.1,2,-83.2991125,231.58275],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,20370,0.1,2,-227.956625,757.027125],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,33030,0.1,2,-301.754875,1045.55275],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,47970,0.1,2,-291.517625,1534.11625],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,63090,0.1,2,-257.7195,1904.9475],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,93090,0.1,2,-32.52868875,1756.22]])
df =pd.DataFrame(original_data,  columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z', '#','Fr', 'Er', 'V', 'R', 'I'])
df1 = df.pivot_table(['R', 'I'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z', '#','Er', 'V'], 'Fr')
df1.to_csv('test.dat', sep='\t', header=True, index=True)
```

and that outpus in a format I can use! (see link below for the desired format)

###End Edit

I have a file that I have managed to bring to a desired format; the original data looks like that [original data](http://pastebin.com/YAGuEi8W)
my desired new format is like this: [desired format](http://pastebin.com/1QKw97B4)

looking around I saw the pivot table function - (df is the dataframe holding the original data)

```
df_desired = df.pivot_table(['R', 'I'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z','#','Er', 'H'], 'Fr')
```

but that gives me only the values for R and I based on Fr (which is what I want, but I want it with all the other data too)

any hints?

Comment: I didn't down vote you but I think it may have been because you did not put sample data in your question and instead pasted links which is frowned upon. You should put data and code that others can use to reproduce your issue including expected output

Comment: @EdChum thanks Ed, I will do that - I believe that the link gives a better / cleaner feel to the question (at least to me) - I think it is unfair to down vote for something I didn't know ; in any away I would expect at least more courteous behavior and at least a comment for the reason of downvoting- thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
original_data = np.array([[1,0,0,10,1530,0.1,2,-49.0756686364,163.856504545],
                 [1,0,0,10,8250,0.1,2,-84.7795213636,264.205363636],
[1,0,0,10,20370,0.1,2,-245.585863636,662.467227273],
[1,0,0,10,33030,0.1,2,-290.468136364,1107.19936364],
[1,0,0,10,47970,0.1,2,-308.668681818,1584.18090909],
[1,0,0,10,63090,0.1,2,-244.954186364,1932.43454545],
[1,0,0,10,93090,0.1,2,-9.5453963636,1794.01636364],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,1530,0.1,2,-36.28640875,136.9883],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,8250,0.1,2,-83.2991125,231.58275],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,20370,0.1,2,-227.956625,757.027125],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,33030,0.1,2,-301.754875,1045.55275],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,47970,0.1,2,-291.517625,1534.11625],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,63090,0.1,2,-257.7195,1904.9475],
[1.5,0.5,0,11,930901,0,0,10,63090,0.1,2,-244.954186364,1932.43454545]

df =pd.DataFrame(original_data,  columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z', '#','Fr', 'Er', 'V', 'R', 'I'])
df1 = df.pivot_table(['R', 'I'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z', '#','Er', 'V'], 'Fr')
df1.to_csv('test.dat', sep='\t', header=True, index=True)
```